# Move PDF page to a different position

Tags: pdf

My question is simple: is there a simple tool that can allow me to move a page or pages of a pdf to a different position? Say page 2 to move to position (page) 55 or something like that. Currently I am using PDF Mod but it is painfully slow for big pdfs. Any recommendations? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `pdfshuffler`. It's available in the repositories:

```
$ apt show pdfshuffler                                                                                                                    
Package: pdfshuffler                                                                                                                                 
Version: 0.6.0-8                                                                                                                                     
Priority: optional                                                                                                                                   
Section: universe/x11                                                                                                                                
Origin: Ubuntu                                                                                                                                       
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>                                                                                
Original-Maintainer: Python Applications Packaging Team <python-apps-team@lists.alioth.debian.org>                                                   
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug                                                                                                     
Installed-Size: 186 kB                                                                                                                               
Depends: python-gtk2, python-poppler, python-pypdf2 | python-pypdf (>= 1.10), python:any (<< 2.8), python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)                          
Homepage: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfshuffler/                                                                                               
Task: ubuntustudio-publishing                                                                                                                        
Download-Size: 31.4 kB                                                                                                                               
APT-Sources: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages                                                                      
Description: merge, split and re-arrange pages from PDF documents
```

From its [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/pdfshuffler.1.html):

> PDF-Shuffler is a small python-gtk application, which helps the user to merge or split pdf
>          documents  and  rearrange  their  pages  using  an  interactive  and  intuitive  graphical
>          interface.   In  the  current  version, page rotation and cropping is also supported. PDF-
>          Shuffler is a frontend for python-pyPdf.

Comment: Thank you it seems to be very much the same PDF Mod that I was using, but this one is much faster. This answers my question

Answer (score 1):

Look at

pdfseperate

and

pdfunite